# How to use a loop to create a CAML query

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

How I would like the CAML Query to look like:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Person 1</Value>
     </Eq>
     <Or>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
           <Value Type='Text'>Person 1</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Or>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
              <Value Type='Text'>Person 3</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Or>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
                 <Value Type='Text'>Person 4</Value>
              </Eq>
              <Or>
                 <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>Person 5</Value>
                 </Eq>
                 <Or>
                    <Eq>
                       <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
                       <Value Type='Text'>Person 6</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                       <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
                       <Value Type='Text'>Person 7</Value>
                    </Eq>
                 </Or>
              </Or>
           </Or>
        </Or>
     </Or>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

What I tried so far:

```
string sC = "<Where>";
int i = myList.Count - 1;
for (int iL = 0; iL < myList.Count; iL++) //for each person add an OR and the person and then another opening OR?
{
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        sC += "<Or>";
    }
    sC += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='ename_090' /><Value Type='Text'>" + myList[iL] + "</Value></Eq>";
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        sC += "<Or>";
    }
    i--;
}
if (myList.Count > 1)
{
      sC += "</Or>";
}
sC += "</Where>";
```

I am just stuck at how can I use a for loop to achieve the above.

Comment: And what's the problem with the code that you have?  What is the CAML that it generates?

Comment: I am stuck at where is it adding the rest of the `</Or>` statement and if only two items left, there is no `<Or>` tag in between.

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation to construct XML (even CAML)... Also usually to build expression tree one would use recursion instead of loop.

Comment: Last `Or` attribute has two `Eq`. is that what it should be or its typo here?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Every `Or` must have exactly two child elements, no more, no less.  Having anything *besides* two child elements would be wrong, so having two is exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do this with recursion.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>
{
    "Person 1",
    "Person 2",
    "Person 3"
};

Func<string,string> Value = x => string.Format("<Value Type = 'Text'>{0}</Value>",x); // Generate Value

Func<string, string> Eq = x => string.Format("<Eq><FieldRef Name = 'ename_090'/>{0}</Eq>", x); // Generate Eq.

Func<string, int, string> Or = null;
Or = (x, i) => string.Format("<Or>{0}{1}</Or>", x,
        i < myList.Count - 2
            ? Or(Eq(Value(myList[i++])), i)
            : i == myList.Count - 2 ? Or(Eq(Value(myList[i++])) + Eq(Value(myList[i])), i) : ""); // Or with recursion call

string sC;
if(myList.Count == 2) // a bit different when length is 2.
{
    sC = string.Format("<Where>{0}</Where>", Or(Eq(Value(myList[0])) + Eq(Value(myList[1])), 2));
}
else
{
    sC = string.Format("<Where>{0}</Where>", Or(Eq(Value(myList[0])), 1)); // start generating
}
```

You have three methods. `Value` which takes Persons names. ex: `myList[0]`,`myList[1]`, etc...

```
<Value Type='Text'>Person 0</Value>
```

`Eq` obviously formats string. So when you do `Eq(Value(myList[0])` you will get one Eq which for example becomes

```
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
    <Value Type='Text'>Person 0</Value>
</Eq>
```

Then you have `Or`. but it also have a call to itself which is called recursion.

So when you do `Or(Eq(Value(myList[0]))` string becomes

```
<Or>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ename_090' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Person 1</Value>
    </Eq>
    {1}
<Or>
```

The part `{1}` will call to itself to continue generating until the last element of list.

**Update:** As suggested by Servy Aggregate is usefull here.

```
Func<string, string> Value = x => string.Format("<Value Type = 'Text'>{0}</Value>", x); // Generate Value

Func<string, string> Eq = x => string.Format("<Eq><FieldRef Name = 'ename_090'/>{0}</Eq>", x); // Generate Eq.

Func<string, string> Or = x => string.Format("<Or>{0}{{0}}</Or>", x);

int i = 0;
string sC = myList.Skip(1).Aggregate(Or(Eq(Value(myList[0]))), (seed, cur) =>
{
    if (i++ < myList.Count - 2)
    {
        return string.Format(seed, Or(Eq(Value(cur))));
    }

    return string.Format(seed, Eq(Value(cur)));
});

sC = string.Format("<Where>{0}</Where>", sC);
```

Comment: This works great except the last two shouldn't have an `<Or>` in between.

Comment: :) Thank you for the help.

Comment: @SiKni8 ok fixed it. i added a condition so the last element will always have two `Eq`.

Comment: Way to go. Seems to be right. Thank you. :) I will test it out and update you.

Comment: i feel like my solution kind of messed up on that condition. Servy solution seems perfect to me. but i try to see if i can make this better.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You're basically just trying to build your own `Aggregate` function.  Don't bother, use the .NET implementation.  It's specifically designed to solve this exact problem.  It also lets us separate out the business logic of this case from the mechanical operation of aggregating items in a sequence, rather than intertwining the two.

Comment: yeah i think thats it. you are adding to my experience sir. Thank you for your explaination. look at update. aggregate really simplified it. but still yours better ;) @Servy

Answer (score 4):

The closing `Or` tag *inside* of your `for` loop is `<Or>` instead of `</Or>`.

First write a method to construct the `Eq` element for an item in your list:

```
public static string TextEquals(string column, string value)
{
    return string.Format(
        "<Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq>",
        column, value);
}
```

Next write a method to wrap two elements in an `Or` element:

```
public static string WrapInOr(string first, string second)
{
    return string.Format("<Or>{0}{1}</Or>", first, second);
}
```

Now that we have this we can take the items in your list, create equals elements for each of them, and then aggregate them all using `Or` elements:

```
var caml = myList.Select(person => TextEquals("ename_090", person))
    .Aggregate((a,b) => WrapInOr(a, b));
```

Outputs:

```
<Or>
    <Or>
        <Or>
            <Or>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="enam_090" />
                        <Value Type="Text">Person 1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="enam_090" />
                        <Value Type="Text">Person 2</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="enam_090" />
                    <Value Type="Text">Person 3</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="enam_090" />
                <Value Type="Text">Person 4</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="enam_090" />
            <Value Type="Text">Person 5</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Or>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="enam_090" />
        <Value Type="Text">Person 6</Value>
    </Eq>
</Or>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It gives tons of `<Or>` at the beginning and there is no `<Or>` in between for the last arguement.

Comment: @SiKni8 And how does that not work?  It's functionally identical to opening the tags as you go and then ending them all at the end.  I've used this solution in lots of applications; it's works perfectly fine.

Comment: I am new to CAML query, will that work correctly to say... Give me the result if match is person 1 OR person 2 OR person 3 OR person 4 OR person 5 OR person 6?

Comment: @SiKni8 "Or" is associative, so (A or B) or C is equivalent to A or (B or C).

Comment: +1 Great solution, never thought that Aggregate method could be so useful. Usually constructed such kind of CAML expressions using recursion

Comment: this is perfect. i suggest if OP really want to keep the order then a simple `myList.Reverse()` before this function can solve his problem.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The order of the items isn't reversed, the depth of the items is reversed.  In my solution the first item is the most deeply nested, rather than the most shallow, but I still have the first person first.  I could mess about with the nesting and reverse it, but it's an entirely non-functional change and doing it this way just comes out more cleanly, so I wouldn't bother without a compelling reason.